# Turn on "Force Gpu Rendering " programmatically

Tags: android, gpu

The minSdk version for my app is 7, my app runs smooth on nexus with ICS as compared to the versions below 3.0, since the min sdk is 7 so i want to switch on gpu rendering option programatically if it is already not enabled for versions above 3.0, ho can i make my app compatible with 2.0 to onward  i.e  enable gpu rendering option for OS>=3.0 only. I want to enable the rendering at the application level, not only at the view level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the application tag of your manifest. It will be ignored by pre Honeycomb devices. Make sure your target sdk is honeycomb or later.

You will need to check that you are not using apis that are for a higher level, but it is not a massive problem. You can get around it with reflection for more complicated tasks or simply by using an if statement, like:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
}
```

There is some more details about this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)

Comment: Yes but in this way i will always have to upload two apk files on the market because i want it install able in pre Honeycomb devices. If i set the target sdk to honeycomb then the IDE will be showing my new methods,  if i  use some methode that is supported for sdk>=3.0, if that apk file is installed on sdk<30 then my app will be crashed,   the hectic solution to that would be checking the API Level of every function call that i will be using onward in my code.

Comment: no you won't. You set it like this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>`

Comment: Scott, i've edited my comment, could you provide little more detailed answer please for the scenario i just mentioned about using the methodes supported by3.0 onward in 2.0 devices ?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some detail on how to code for multiple versions.

Comment: Thankyou scott, your answer has been of great help. Actually i was trying to avoid this  "new methods conflict", though there is no other way except to check that the method you are using is supported from which API Level onward. Page you suggested also says that we should set the target sdk verison to the latest availble version and add the checks on  versions before using new methods.